# Scrapy mixing and repeats items fields from different pages

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, mixed

Comrades, I need your help, I was tortured to turn the day on it. My Item data is repeated and shuffled from different pages. This is my code.

```py
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.job['start_url'], callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        for  subcat in response.xpath("//div[@id='nav-menu-group']/nav[@id='menu']/ul/li[@class='_category-link-wrapper current selected  ']/ul[@class='_subcategories current']/li")[7:-2]:
            Item = WebscrapyItem()
            url = subcat.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
            if url:
                Item['category'] = self.job['category']
                Item['subcategory'] = subcat.xpath('./a/span//text()').extract_first()

                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, meta={'Item': Item}, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        Item = response.meta['Item']
        for product in response.xpath('//ul[@class="product-list _productList  "]/li'):

            url = product.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
            if url:
                Item['dt'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                Item['product_id'] = product.xpath('./@id').extract_first()
                Item['url'] = url

                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, meta={'Item': Item}, callback=self.parse_details)


    def parse_details(self, response):
        Item = response.meta['Item']
        other_data = json.loads(response.xpath('//section[@id="product"]/script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first())
        Item['data'] = {
        'header': response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section']/header/h1/text()").extract_first(),
        'price': other_data[0]['offers']['price'],
        'priceCurrency': other_data[0]['offers']['priceCurrency'],
        'colorName': response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section']/div[@class='product-info-wrapper _product-info'][1]/p[@class='product-color']/span[@class='_colorName']/text()").extract_first(),
        'reference': response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section']/div[@class='product-info-wrapper _product-info'][1]/p[@class='product-color']/span[2]/text()").extract_first(),
        'description': response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section']/div[@class='product-info-wrapper _product-info'][1]/div[@id='description']/p[@class='description']/text()").extract_first(),
        'sizeList': response.xpath("//div[@class='info-section']/form[@class='_product-detail-actions']/fieldset[@class='size-selector _size-selector opened ']/div[@class='size-select']/div[@class='size-list']/label/span/text()").extract_first(),
        'other_data': other_data,
        }
        yield Item
```

I created the Item object before and after the for loop, but it didn’t work. Data is recorded in mongodb with repetitions and mixed. When exporting to json is the same.

pleese help...

Comment: Changed the value in settings.py and uncommented CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1. I hope someone will come in handy.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables. Maybe you read the same values from different pages. It also can help you see where can be problem.

Comment: in `for` in `parse_data` you use the same item - and later it may use the same item intead of many different instances. Maybe you should duplicate/copy it inside `for` loop.

Comment: Early was happy, the change CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1 did not help. The data is repeated in one stream with CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1. I don’t know what to think.

Comment: Because Python uses references instead of duplicate object  so in `parse_data` you use the same `Item` for all products. All products use the same space in memory to keep data and finally you get the same values in all rows. Inside `for`loop you have to create new `Item` for every product and copy values from old `Item` or use `new_item = copy.deepcopy(Item)`

Comment: Big Thanks furas, you help me, very big master )))